# Python scikit svm "Vocabulary not fitted or provided"

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, pickle, tfidfvectorizer

Playing around with Python's scikit SVM Linear Support Vector Classification and I'm running into an error when I attempt to make predictions:

```
import pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk import word_tokenize
import string


# Function to pass the list to the Tf-idf vectorizer
def returnPhrase(inputList):
    return inputList


# Pre-processing the sentence which we input to predict the emotion
def transformSentence(sentence):
    s = []
    sentence = sentence.replace('\n', '')
    sentTokenized = word_tokenize(sentence)
    s.append(sentTokenized)
    sWithoutPunct = []
    punctList = list(string.punctuation)
    curSentList = s[0]
    newSentList = []
    for word in curSentList:
        if word.lower() not in punctList:
            newSentList.append(word.lower())
    sWithoutPunct.append(newSentList)
    mystemmer = PorterStemmer()
    tokenziedStemmed = []
    for i in range(0, len(sWithoutPunct)):
        curList = sWithoutPunct[i]
        newList = []
        for word in curList:
            newList.append(mystemmer.stem(word))
        tokenziedStemmed.append(newList)
    return tokenziedStemmed


# Extracting the features for SVM
myVectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', tokenizer=returnPhrase, preprocessor=returnPhrase,
                               token_pattern=None,
                               ngram_range=(1, 3))

# The SVM Model
curC = 2  # cost factor in SVM
SVMClassifier = svm.LinearSVC(C=curC)

filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# Input sentence
with open('trial_truth_001.txt', 'r') as file:
    sent = file.read().replace('\n', '')

transformedTest = transformSentence(sent)

X_test = myVectorizer.transform(transformedTest).toarray()
Prediction = loaded_model.predict(X_test)

# Printing the predicted emotion
print(Prediction)
```

It's when I attempt to use the LinearSVC to predict that I'm informed:

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided
```

What am I missing here? Obviously it is the way I fit and transform the data.

Comment: you need to use the vectorizer on which you have trained the model. in your code you are creating  object for tfidfvectorizer and than using it with transform, which will throw the error.. so you  need to save vectorizer when training the model and than using the same vectorizer for prediction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to change the line

```
X_test = myVectorizer.transform(transformedTest).toarray()
```

to

```
X_test = myVectorizer.fit_transform(transformedTest).toarray()
```